# How to return two parameter from function

Tags: python, function

I am quite new to python programming and I need some help solving a problem with the function below :

```py
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
    string = first_name, last_name

    if string == first_name and last_name:
      return ('Name: ' + last_name + ', ' + first_name)

    elif string == '' and last_name:
      return ('Name: ' + last_name)

    elif string == first_name and '':
      return ('Name: ' + first_name)

    else:
      return ''

    return string
```

The desired outputs :

```py
print(format_name("Ernest", "Hemingway"))
```

should return the string `Name: Hemingway, Ernest` ;

```py
    print(format_name("", "Madonna"))
```

should return the string `Name: Madonna`;

```py
print(format_name("Voltaire", ""))
```

should return the string `Name: Voltaire` ;

```py
print(format_name("", ""))
```

should return an empty string.

Can anyone point out my mistake ?

Comment: Return a tuple of 2!

Comment: None of your conditions will ever match. You are comparing a tuple with strings,

Comment: Printing is not the same thing as returning. Saying that print(format_name("", "Madonna"))` 'Should return the string "Name: Madonna"' doesn't make a lot of sense. The word "return" there should be replaced by "print". In some ways I am being picky, but confusing `print` and `return` is a common mistake of first-time programmers learning Python.

Comment: And your `return string` can not be reached.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are compering a string with a tuple which is always `False`
`string = first_name, last_name` string value will be a tuple like this `('fname', 'lname')` and of course it's not equals to any string.

If you want to return multiple values as a returning value of the function you can do something like this:

```
def func():
  return "first string", "second string"
```

This will return the following tuple `("first string", "second string")`

You can receive it as the following:

```
first, second = func()
```

`first` will be `"first string"` as a string and `second` will be `"second string"` as a string too in this case

You can check after that according your program logic.

Hope that somehow helped